# How to Replace DTE2 in .NET Standard

Tags: c#, .net-standard, envdte, .net-standard-2.0

It's been a while since `.NET Standard` is introduced by Microsoft. Earlier, if I wanted to obtain information about `Project`, `Solution` and other related objects (e.g solution path, projects in a solution, etc), I used `DTE2` type which is an interface inside `EnvDTE80` assembly. But `EnvDTE80` isn't compatible with `.NET Standard`.
Any idea how to turn around this problem? Is there a replacement at all?

By the way, I'm currently using `.NET Standard 2.0`, if it matters.

Comment: This is related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46573802/how-can-i-use-envdte-within-a-net-standard-project with a relevant comment, but no answer.

Comment: As Visual Studio is clearly Windows only, like .NET Framework, there is no significant need to develop `DTE` related things to .NET Standard. To process projects or solutions, you can also use MSBuild/Roslyn instead.

Comment: @LexLi Could you please describe more and give me some information about how to use MSBuild in my code? For example, how to get the solution's path using MSBuild.

Answer (score 2):

This is a very late answer, but for anyone needing to do this in 2022 there are now compatible NuGet packages for this:

[image]